# How to set a Work Manager to listen to an unlock screen event (android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT)

Tags: java, android, android-workmanager

I'm trying to set up an Android Work Manager in Java which is triggered every Time the screen gets unlocked.

With Android <= 8 it was possible to use the Broadcast service and define the triggers in the manifest.xml like shown [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts#manifest-declared-receivers)

However, I could not find any information on how to listen to such events like screen unlocked (android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT) with the "new" Work Manager.

Comment: AFAIK, `WorkManager` has no option for this, sorry.

Comment: @CommonsWare Is there any other way to accomplish this.

Comment: I don't see it on the broadcast implicit `Intent` allowlist, but I expected to see it there. If the manifest-registered receiver is not working, then I do not have a good solution for you to find out about this event in the background.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I will try to ask in a more general way again and hope to find a solution.